# Add context path for an app on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Nginx servers all the static content from the root directory to the root URL. For example if the root content location is configured as `/usr/share/nginx/html` which contains a file `/usr/share/nginx/html/foo.html`, then the url `http://localhost/foo.html` will serve that html file. I want to prefix a context path in the URL such that `http://localhost/myapp/foo.html` should serve `/usr/share/nginx/html/foo.html` file.

I tried changing the location and adding an alias but that gives a 404.

```
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /myapp/ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  }
```

I also want that `http://localhost/myapp` should serve `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

I'm using nginx's `1.12.1-alpine` docker image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
  index  index.html index.htm;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location /myapp/ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  }
```

If that doesn't work then try below

```
  index  index.html index.htm;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location /myapp/ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```

**Edit-1**

If you want it to work without trailing / then you should use below

```
location ~ /app(/.*)?$ {
   alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'm trying with a trailing slash as I've written it in the question as well.

Comment: The config is 100% correct. I have tested it locally. I guess you have some other default config also lying around in your nginx config which may be the issue. Add the output of `find . -name "*.conf"` in the folder where your `nginx.conf` folder is present

Comment: That worked after some trying. The only thing that root url without a trailing slash (`http://localhost/myapp`) returns 404 where `http://localhost/myapp/` returns `index.html`

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the OP's conf was returning 404? I fail to understand what the problem was

Comment: I think `index index.html` was not outside that is why.

Comment: @ares we are having the same issue. How you able to fix it?