# Kubernetes Ingress with AWS ALB Controller

Tags: kubernetes, url-rewriting, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I am using an EKS cluster and deployed AWS Load Balancer Controller for ingress. Using a dummy application (taken Nginx image) deployed one service. Just for the test, I am trying to access the same service from 3 different ingress paths: **/** and **/foo/** and **/bar/**

AWS is successfully provisioning an ALB while ingress kubernetes object is getting deployed.
I am able to access the dummy application (Nginx homepage) by hitting external ALB on path '/'.

**http://alb-dns/** # it's opening the Nginx homepage
But **http://alb-dns/foo/** and **http://alb-dns/bar/** are throwing "404 Not Found" error.

I searched through the internet and probably the issue is with URL rewrite. But the problem is, AWS ALB Controller does not support URL rewrite.

I tried lot of options mentioned in the below links but none of them works:

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#actions

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/835

Is there any alternative to URL redirect? How do I get Nginx Homepage using http://alb-dns/foo/ url?

Or it's better to dump AWS LB Controller and move to Nginx Controller?

Thanks in advance.

These are Kubernetes manifests I am using:

```html
---
# Source: game-app/templates/game-app-namespace.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-fargate-app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sample-game-app
---
# Source: game-app/templates/game-app-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: ns-fargate-app
  name: game-app-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sample-game-app
---
# Source: game-app/templates/game-app-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ns-fargate-app
  name: sample-game-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: sample-game-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: sample-game-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.21
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: sample-game-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        

# Source: game-app-ingress/templates/game-app-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ns-fargate-app
  name: game-app-ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /foo/
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: game-app-service
                port:
                   number: 80
        - path: /bar/
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: game-app-service
                port:
                   number: 80
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: game-app-service
                port:
                   number: 80
```

AWS ALB (Active)
[image]

Three ALB Rules

[image]

http:/alb-dns**/** (Working fine)

[image]

http:/alb-dns**/foo** (Throwing 404 error)

[image]

Comment: Are foo and bar apps part of nginx image which is used. Which will serve /foo and /bar requests

Comment: can you share what has been created under the ALB rules? did the 3x rules has been created successfully?

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal - Yes all are same Nginx image (public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.21). So, / and /foo and /bar all are pointing to game-app-service.

Comment: @a.k - Yes three rules have been created which is pointing to the same service/backend. Only root path (/) is working.

Comment: As the nginx homepage with version is seen it means the requests are reaching nginx server(sample-game-app).  that is serving root path /.  for /foo to work in that context path there should sample app or your own app to receive the request and respond.  in this case game-app-service is plain nginx server whether is there redirection or routing /foo in nginx to a different microservice/app

Comment: Thanks @NatarajMedayhal. Is there any way I can redirect from /foo to / so that Nginx can serve the request? I am using AWS LB Controller.

Comment: rewrite annotation can be used to achieve redirection https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal Problem is I am using AWS Load Balancer Controller; not Nginx Ingress Controller.

Comment: AWS alb doesnt support rewrite

Comment: Raised a GitHub issue for the same # https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2713

Answer (score 0):

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource.

Prefix  /   matches all paths.

Your paths /foo/ and /bar/ are redundant in game-app-ingress.yaml. Does your Nginx instance respond to /foo/ or /bar/? If not, that's why you're getting the 404.

See [Add context path for an app on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981794/add-context-path-for-an-app-on-nginx) for adding additional contexts to your Nginx instance for /foo/ and /bar/.

Since game-app-service has the root path, you can remove the paths for /foo/ and /bar/.